# Почему Slick показывает больше чем нужно, не адаптируется и вообще не реагирует на ширину окна и дает скролл?

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

Добрый день коллеги,
Прошу вас помочь победить злополучный слайдер.

ЗАДАЧА: аккуратно рассадить итемы по ширине контейнера и соответственно выводить то количество, что указано в настройках.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

САБЖ: Как он ведет себя - вы можете ["заценить" тут](http://dev.imdeveloper.ru/v-registration/).

1. Не реагирует на изменение размера окна
2. "Прячет" стрелки при окне уже 1000 пикс.
3. Не адаптируется ни разу.

Настройки

```js
$('.product__list').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  variableWidth: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="product-next">&nbsp;</button>',
  prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="product-prev">&nbsp;</button>',
   responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 800,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 500,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]

});
```

ЗЫ Переезжать на другой плагин на данном проекте не могу. Прошу принять как одно из условий задачи. Надеюсь на ваше понимание.

Заранее ОГРОМНОЕ Спасибо!!!

Comment: Странное поведение конечно... Единственное что могу я предложить - на класс `"new-product "` нацепить `margin: 0 auto;width: 80%;`. А вы пробовали поместить сам слайдер (в том виде что есть сейчас) просто в body ? дело в том, что хоть там и написано про адаптивность, он адаптивен относительно родительского блока

Comment: Ваше решение и правда частично сработало, но все равно эта зараза не адаптивиться как надо: не выводит требуемое число итемов. Шикарный же плагин был...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ou53b1qs/ - набросал быстрый пример, где слайдер вроде как реагирует на изменение ширины окна. Но я не писал брэкпоинты - по сути их можно поставить на базовые значения - 1024, 1280 и >1281. Я бы вам посоветовал заного переверстать родительский блок для слайдера - возможно в нем кроется причина. Иногда легче выкинуть и сделать заного =)

Comment: А насчет обрезания элементов по бокам - можно сделать это "фичей", поставив в настройках слайдера отображение по центру. А с количеством элементов действительно трабла есть. Может быть стоит обновить библиотеку ? (может вы используете старую версию?) или же с jquery ту же операцию произвести.

Comment: @alexoander Капитально прицепилась к брейкпоинктам, и знаете - помогло!!! Хоть не так ужасно все стало... ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЮ ЧИТАТЬ НАДА!!!(*ор на себя)
Квери поменяла на 1.8.2 (стояла 1.4. Не мешала. Надо жеже О_о) - чутка полегчало!
Поковыряю теперь со стрелками и отпишу по результату!

Comment: Рад за вас и ваше упорство) Если найдете "лечение" данной траблы - отпишите тут и пометьте как ответ. Чтобы помочь кому-то еще с такой же проблемой =) К тому же у вас уже получилось весьма сносно - надо чутка только поправить исчезновение стрелок на 1030 px

Comment: @alexoander 
И так - есть решение
1. Указывать ВСЕ брейкпоинты
2. Давать доп обертку для слайдера и ей - отступы, для того, чтобы были видны стрелки
3. Следить за версией JQwery.
Актуальный фикс - [тут](http://dev.imdeveloper.ru/v-registration/)

Answer (score 1):

И так - есть решение

1. Указывать ВСЕ брейкпоинты
2. Давать доп обертку для слайдера и ей - отступы, для того, чтобы были видны стрелки
3. Следить за версией JQwery.

Актуальный фикс - [тут](http://dev.imdeveloper.ru/v-registration/)

Comment: Ну выглядит теперь приятней) Молодец!